# Can we do a partition on the hard disk when uTorrents are downloaded halfway?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, partitioning

I'm using uTorrent and have about 30 files "half-downloaded".

I was wondering am I able to exit uTorrent, partition my hard disk,  and resume the downloads with no errors?

Or does uTorrent does some meta stuff which, if I do as above, would put the downloads in "invalid state" ?

My files are downloaded into `D:\downloads` and I'm trying to shift 10.95 GB unallocated into `D:\`.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**BitTorrent downloads are files, nothing more.** As long as the files are not deleted, and as long as the original `.torrent` file exists, you can resume the download just fine.

Besides, **resizing only moves the data around,** it doesn't destroy anything the filesystem has. The metadata (*file names*, dates, security, streams) is part of the filesystem and is preserved as well.

(If μTorrent even tried to store anything *outside* the filesystem, it 1. wouldn't be allowed to do so, without Administrator rights; 2. would quickly become unpopular for storing data the most stupid way ever.)

Comment: Yeah, worried about a uTorrent download being destroyed by a repartition is like being worried that the word .doc you're working on being destroyed by a repartition. The risk is there but it has nothing to do with the nature of the file itself.

Answer (score 4):

Torrents are remarkably resilient. I've had files that I've downloaded with BitTorrent that I've moved from one computer/file system to another that, at some point, have become corrupted in some way. Instead of having to either cut my losses or to incur another lengthy download (the example I have in mind was a 6+GB file) all I had to do was find and re-download the right torrent and replace the file that it's downloading into with my corrupted file. Upon restarting, I triggered a recheck and uTorrent happily reported that I had 99.7% of the file and downloaded the rest.

So to answer your question, yes, you can safely move partial downloads around as much as you like as long as you keep the original .torrent file or can redownload it. And you can usually move partial downloads between different torrent apps without skipping a beat.